# How to eliminate a repeating tree hierarchy for the types that share the same structure?

Tags: info-visualisation, data, tree, simplicity

Below there is a modal where I have three categories that contain the same tree structure.

Is there a way I can consolidate or simplify these three structures into one or maybe restructure this in a way where I don't have to repeat the tree several times?

[image]

Comment: Have three checkboxes (labelled appropriately) per item in the one tree?

Comment: Can you clarify the task? Does the user need to choose one of A, B or C or are multiple choices OK? Can the user choose A, B or C without choosing any of the categories underneath? Can the user choose one of the categories under type A, B or C without choosing the type itself?

Answer (score 2):

That's a right decision not to repeat the tree three times. Thus, a task can be set this way:

> How to allow selection of three types (A, B and C) at each node of a tree structure?

Assuming that each node can represent a subtree, a toggle buttons group can be used for this purpose with the following states defined:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKIYdZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It will result in a layout like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fshawZ.png)</sup>

And this, for the case when all top-level nodes are folded:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6FRtE.png)</sup>

Please, note that a leaf node (the one with no children) cannot be in second state (some childs selected). A user can only select and unselect it, while such state resolves automatically for its parent node.

Answer (score 1):

Your sketch shows checkbox - can user check 2 categories and positions below or its impossible?

For now I would do something like that:
[image: version 1]

or something like this

[image: version 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table, similar to tables describing the features included or not depending on the plan chosen.

[image]

Your table would be much simpler. Columns would be type A, B, C, and the rows would be business services, consumer good, etc.

I think it would make it easier for the user who want only 1 category for all 3 types, to check 3 boxes next to each other, rather than switch tab or change the dropdown menu.

I would also give a good overview of which categories are included for each type, without having to open sub-folders.